# transfer api on ethereum web3 contract, How it is not possible changing "from" parameter on main net?

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts

I'm new in Dapp. and researching how to make dapp. 
and I found some codes like this. transferring tokens between wallets

```
Token.transfer(accounts[1], 10, {from:accounts[2]}).then(function(result){
      console.log(result)
    })
```

This will send 10 tokens from account[2] to account[1]

I understand this is development mode and it can handles all accounts.

But, I don't know How it is not possible in production?
I can't find any thing about this..

Does any user can call this api changing from address?
If not, How it is not?

I think there should be some preventing code user cannot change from value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test RPC network, all account could be unlocked. 
All unlocked accounts can be handled without signed transaction.

you can unlock/lock account using command

```
web3.personal.unlockAccount(address);
web3.personal.lockAccount(address);
```

If you lock account, you can't use 'transfer' function directly without signed transaction.

Refer: [How to make signed transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46611117/how-to-authenticate-and-send-contract-method-using-web3-js-1-0)

- All account will be locked as a default in eth main network.

Answer (score -1):

For transfer purposes in erc20 tokens, there are 2 methods, `Transfer` and `TransferFrom`.

If you are using transfer method you have to sign transaction with `FromAccount` private key.

If you are using `TransferFrom` you have to set Allowance for `FromAccount` to `ToAccount` in previous transaction (signed by `FromAccount` private key). You can't transfer tokens from `FromAccount` without transactions signed with `FromAccount` private key even in develop network.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. This would not be considered a "complete" answer, and would perhaps be better served as a comment. For a complete answer, you would need to provide verifiable working code, or clear defined steps towards a solution. 

Looking at your answer, you could probably edit this and supply more information, in order to reach a complete answer. Consider your structuring.

Comment: The question was: Does any user can call this api changing from address? If not, How it is not? Answer is - you cannot change fromAccount to whatever you want. Why it is so is described in my answer